# Pagination using AngularJS/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I would like to set up a pagination like:
[image]

```
    I saw this Plunker, but it does not fit my expectations 
    (Too complicated):
    http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

An idea?
```

Answer (score 1):

An example with working tag pagination

[pagination with ng-repeat](http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/)